# Apollo REFSMMAT components

Tags: navigation, apollo-15

[image: Apollo 15 Landing Site REFSMMAT]

In the snip above, under
(b) Definition of REFSMMAT, there is a 3x3 Matrix depicted. Under
(c) REFSMMAT Components, a list of the value of each of the 9 components of the 3x3 Matrix using Unit Vectors is given.

Does each row of the matrix represent a point in either the Earth-centered (ECI), or Moon-centered (MCI) Inertial Coordinate System?

Comment: This figure shows you how to compute the REFSMMAT matrix for the landing site. [![Landing site REFSMMAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9bhn.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M9bhn.jpg) I am curious: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

> Does each row of the matrix represent a point in either the Earth-centered (ECI), or Moon-centered (MCI) Inertial Coordinate System?

Each row represents a direction rather than a point. Interpreted as vectors, each row corresponds to a unit vector. The first row of an Apollo REFSMMAT was the unit vector expressed in Mean of 1950 (M50 for short) coordinates that points to the stable platform $\hat x$ axis. Similarly, the second and third rows are unit vectors that represent the stable platform $\hat y$ and $\hat z$ axes, once again expressed in M50 coordinates.

The columns have a similar meaning. Interpreted as vectors, the columns of an orthonormal transformation matrix are the representations of unit vectors directed along the parent frame's (in this case M50) principal axes but represented in child frame (in this case stable platform) coordinates.

Since each row / each column corresponds to a unit vector, each element is the dot product of a pair unit vectors, one in the M50 frame and the other in the stable platform frame. The dot product between two vectors is $\vec{v_1} \cdot \vec{v_2} = ||\vec{v_1}||\, ||\vec{v_2}|| \cos\theta$, where $\theta$ is the angle between the two vectors. With a pair of unit vectors, this reduces to $\cos\theta$. This is why another name for a transformation matrix is a direction cosine matrix.

Comment: While technically correct, I don't feel that this answered the question in the slightest.

Comment: @Innovine The question asks whether each row represents a point. That doesn't make sense. Each row represents a direction.

Answer (score 1):

No. The 3x3 matrix is a [direction cosine matrix](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/PlanetPhysics/Direction_Cosine_Matrix).

> The cosine matrix defining its M50 attitude is called a Reference Stable Member
> Matrix (REFSMMAT).

Attitude and Pointing
Flight Procedures Handbook, [JSC-10511](https://gandalfddi.z19.web.core.windows.net/Shuttle/JSC-10511%20-%20Attitude%20and%20Positioning%20Flight%20Procedures%20Handbook%2019850101.pdf)
Revision A, Page 9-3